# Panel crosses the bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with the bottom panel.
I have that 2 panels.
[First panel (top) and second panel (bottom)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYH9G.png)

But, when I increment the height of the first panel, the second panel hides in the bottom of the page

[Problem with the second panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsEO6.png)

How do I fix that?

This is the CSS of the second panel.

```
.form-panelAtributos {
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

#panelAtributos {
    min-height:1%!important;
    max-height:34%!important;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;    
}

.panelBodyAtributos {
    padding-bottom: 15px !important;
    padding-top: 15px !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;    
}
```

Edit: And this is my html:

```
<div id="panelAtributos" class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="headPanel" class="panel-heading"></div>
    <div id="panelBody" class="panel-body panelBodyAtributos">
        <form id="cuerpoAtributos" class="form-panelAtributos form-horizontal">
        </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add your HTML

Comment: Use `display: flex;` on the parent and `flex-direction: column;` - also read this [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)